# Can't install firebase dependencies from pubspec.yaml in flutter?

Tags: android, database, firebase, flutter, pubspec

I am using a flutter in my mobile app and I have a problem of installing firebase dependencies in pubspec.yaml file. It gave an error. I tried many ways and I couldn't figure it out. any help ?
[This is an error code from bub I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5aGH.png)

Comment: Try changing all the package versions to 'any'. then share the error it shows then.

Comment: update url_launcher version to `url_launcher: ^6.1.0`

Comment: I tried url_launcher: ^6.1.0 and It works fine for me. Many thank you for both sharing your knowledge and  it's lot to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the package version of url_launcher:6.1.0
https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher
I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when one plugin version is incompatible with another plugin it depends on.

To resolve the issue, make sure both plugin versions are compatible; and in this, case, you should update `update url_launcher` to `url_launcher: ^6.1.0`.